# Send an ID to by using (click)=function({{ID}})?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a json from my server, In the json, I have ID for each element. How can I add the ID of each element to each tap function.

```
    <ion-card (tap)="detail({{post.Ads_ID}})">
      <img src="http://www.elleoncito.com/admin/images/default_slider.jpg"/>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{post.Title}}
          </ion-card-title>
        <p>
          The most popular industrial group ever, and largely
          responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
        </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Comment: FYI: you tagged this with angularjs instead of angular.

Answer (score 0):

don't give post.Ads_ID in mustache. See the below code

```
<ion-card (tap)="detail(post.Ads_ID)">
      <img src="http://www.elleoncito.com/admin/images/default_slider.jpg"/>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{post.Title}}
          </ion-card-title>
        <p>
          The most popular industrial group ever, and largely
          responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
        </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @Hein please mark the answer as accepted if you think it fixes the issue, so we can close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----) documentation

> You use interpolation to weave calculated strings into the text
>   between HTML element tags and within attribute assignments.

However, if you were to use event binding (i.e., (click)="someFunc(value)"), it would be treated as a variable and the interpolation wouldn't be required.

In order to resolve your issue, you need to remove interpolation from `(tap)="detail({{post.Ads_ID}})"` and change it to `(tap)="detail(post.Ads_ID)"`.
This should resolve your issue.